# configobj multiple configurations

Tags: python, configobj

I am a new programmer working on a program that contains a list of recipes which can be searched and then generate menu from a selected commonality.

My initial thought has been to use a configuration file to store the data (I am using `configobj` for python). The problem here is that a value (e.g. `ingredients = []`) will occur several times.

Is there a way to separate different configurations within a single file? something like

```
Recipe
{
    value0 = 
}
Recipe 2
{
    value0 =
}
```

I am trying to avoid having ascending values (`value1(n),value1(n+1)`) or using a config file for each recipe.

Alternatively if this is not possible, could someone suggest an alternative file structure, including those not using `configobj`.

Comment: @Bishan, thanks for the edits, I will try to follow the style more closely when posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want human-editable ini-like format:

```
[Recipe]
value0 = ..

[Recipe2]
value0 = ..
```

If the file is used to exchange data between programs then you could use (also human-readable) json format:

```
{ "Recipe": { "value0": ".." }, "Recipe2": { "value0": ".." } }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the first is what I am looking for. I believe those headers are called sections.